# Configure multiple websites using one core (CakePHP)

Tags: php, .htaccess, cakephp

I have a system runing on my webserver in /my_system folder

I need to duplicate it, for 2 new websites. They'll use the SAME system, but different databases.

I need to place them in specific folders.
Like:

- /my_system/client_1
- /my_system/client_2
- /my_system/client_3

Then I can use url prefix to guess which client I want and which database I need.

Tthe configuration was very easy, by using .htaccess and just editing some lines in database.php

But now I'm having a problem:

When I try to access /my_system/client_1/Page/1, instead of search in Pages controller, Cake tries to search the client_1 controller, which doesn't exists.
I've tried to add the client_1, client_2, client_3 to routes prefix (Configure::write('Routing.prefixes', array('client_1', 'client_2'));), but didn't worked.

So, what's the best way to work with it?
BY only using Rewrite in htaccess I can deal with it?

Obs.:
If I try to access /my_system/Page/1 I can access it normally, the only thing I need to do is work with the mentioned prefixes.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd deal with this using [CakePHP's routes](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html).

They wouldn't be prefixes because you already have a prefix of 'my_system'.

Comment: Instead of using prefixes I just re-route all pages and now it's just select a different database for each different websites. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this great yet simple article

[CAKEPHP 3 – DEFINING THE CORE OUTSIDE WEBROOT](http://www.sixteenink.com/cakephp-3-defining-the-core-outside-webroot/)

You might be able to do the same with version 2.x

Comment: I don't think this is what he's asking.  It was a bit confusing question, so I could be wrong too, but I think he's asking how to have 3 websites share a single CakePHP App (as opposed to just sharing the core CakePHP files)

Comment: For maintenance reasons I do not think it is convenient to share the same app, it could lead to a messy code, a more complex server configuration in case one of them has a specific need... and I could be wrong with this too. It isn't always bad to duplicate something!

Comment: Dave is right, I'm trying to share a single App to 3 websites. I've managed to do that with routes. I was trying to do it by using prefixes but it wasn't a good approach.

Comment: I don't think you or I can say what would work best for this person.  In most cases, for me, it's MUCH easier to share the code base - think of it like a single app that displays multiple mini websites... in that case WHY would you duplicate all your code to store in multiple places - that seems like a nightmare.

Comment: I just thought about it: In the last 5 weeks, I had to edit the system 200 times. And I WILL change it again. I just can't update 3 websites at the same time ... Something always is gonna be left behind.

Comment: In my last comment I just shared a thought about a possible situation, I didn't say that's the panacea nor this was "what would work best for this person!" I was thinking that maybe @StiveKnx has 3 websites because each of them share most of the code but have some specific features. That's a situation not a nightmare.